# use wget to output everything retrieved into a single txt file

Tags: download, website, wget

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
wget --recursive --output-document=theEntirePagestuffedIntoATextfile.txt www.example.com
```

And in words what it should do is: "download the entire website www.example.com and stuff it into a giant textfile".

Answer (score 0):

```
wget www.google.com | tee file
```